# Mathematica 12 HighlightImage doubles image dimensions ! Bug?

Tags: bugs, image-processing

My scripts that use HighlightImage stopped working after upgrading to 12.
I discovered that HighlightImage doubles the Dimensions of the image, see below. Bug ?? workaround ? I need the exact same image as the original, only with a marker superimposed.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't happen for me on 12.1.1 Windows 10. Try `Options[img2, PlotRange]` to see if it's inflating the plot range. It's either that, or the image is scaled after marking it.

Comment: I'm not sure this warrants the bugs tag. I have a feeling this is by design.

Answer (score 10):

`HighlightImage` returns a `Graphics` object, not an `Image`.

```
HighlightImage[img, {120, 120}] // Head
```

> ```
> Graphics
> ```

When you call `ImageDimensions`, `Rasterize` is invoked internally to create an `Image` object to find the dimensions of. I believe it was V12 that `Rasterize` got an overhaul to work with high dpi screens.

A regular screen is 72 dpi (or 96 on Windows I think). Modern macs are 144 though:

```
$OperatingSystem
```

> ```
> "MacOSX"
> ```

```
CurrentValue["ConnectedDisplays"]
```

> ```
> {{"Region" -> {{0., 1680.}, {23., 1050.}}, 
>  "FullRegion" -> {{0., 1680.}, {0., 1050.}}, 
>  "PixelDimensions" -> {3360, 2100}, "BitDepth" -> 32, 
>  "Resolution" -> 144., "Scale" -> 2.}}
> ```

We can fix this by calling `Rasterize` with a custom dpi setting:

```
img2 = Rasterize[im, ImageResolution -> 72];
ImageDimensions[img2]
```

> ```
> {240, 240}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for that, Chip ! I was pulling my hair out. I am close to a hard deadline and this was going to kill me dead,